# hibernet search wildcard with 2 words

Tags: lucene, wildcard

I am querying with 2 words, namely "test" and "tests".  I want something like this:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = (org.apache.lucene.search.Query) qb 
        .keyword()
        .wildcard()
        .onFields("jobTitle", "tags", "role", "DepartmentName",
        "skillSet", "longDescription", "designation",
        "qualification", "desiredSkill", "location")
    .matching("test* tests*").createQuery();`
```

If I put `wildcard()`, then these 2 words will be considered as one.